# retrieving top ten records from csv file using asp/php/asp.net

Tags: csv, asp-classic, vbscript

I am using Asp scripting lang, I want to disaply top ten records from a csv file. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

While looping through the CSV file, you could create a variable and increment it with each iteration and once it reaches 10, you exit out of the loop:

**PHP Example**

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($csv as $line)
{
  $counter++;

  // your code........

  if ($counter === 10) break;
}
```

**ASP Example**

```
Dim Counter
Counter = 0
For Each line In csv
  Counter = Counter + 1

  ' your code

  If Counter = 10 Exit For
Next
```

Comment: huh.. I mean to say, i want to get details of 10 students who are scoring highest marks from csv file